# Badge icon not updating in Samsung phone

Tags: android, push-notification, samsung-mobile, badge, samsung

The badge icon is not getting updated when receiving a notification on an Android Samsung S10+ phone.
It sets to 0 when an app gets installed and 16 when receiving a notification.

It's working fine on other Android devices and other Samsung devices as well.